# Build errors when installing wxHaskell on Linux

Tags: linux, haskell, wxhaskell

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 and trying to install wxHaskell. I installed wxWidgets 2.9 from the `http://repos.codelite.org/wx3.0/ubuntu/` repository.

The basic `cabal install wx` gets me

```
src/cpp/eljgrid.cpp:61:65: error: no matching function for call to ‘wxGridCellEditor::PaintBackground(wxRect, wxGridCellAttr*)’
  self->PaintBackground(wxRect(x, y, w, h), (wxGridCellAttr*)attr);
                                                                 ^
[...]
wxcore-0.90.0.3 depends on wxc-0.90.0.4 which failed to install.
```

Downloading from the GitHub repository and building from source gets me:

```
setup: can't find source for Graphics/UI/WXCore/WxcClassInfo in src/haskell,
dist/build/autogen
Failed to install wxcore-0.90.1.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
wxcore-0.90.1.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring wx-0.90.1.0...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
wxcore >=0.90.1.0
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: wx-0.90.1.0
trying: wx-0.90.1.0:+splitbase
rejecting: wxcore-0.90.0.3, 0.90.0.1, 0.90, 0.13.2.3, 0.13.2.1, 0.13.2,
0.12.1.7, 0.12.1.6, 0.12.1.5, 0.12.1.4, 0.12.1.3, 0.12.1.2, 0.12.1.1,
0.11.1.2, 0.11.1.1, 0.11.1.0, 0.11.0, 0.10.13.0, 0.10.13, 0.10.12, 0.10.11,
0.10.10, 0.10.9, 0.10.8, 0.10.7, 0.10.6, 0.10.5, 0.10.4, 0.10.3, 0.10.2,
0.10.1 (conflict: wx-0.90.1.0:splitbase => wxcore>=0.90.1.0)
```

What's going on with this and what's required to fix it?

Comment: I don't remember the specifics, but for some reason the wxHaskell package is currently broken. There is a working fork, but for the love of me I can't remember where it was. I'm sure you'll find it if you actively look for it.

Comment: I saw a reference to this on a mailing list, with the fork being at https://github.com/atzedijkstra/wxHaskell. However, that URL now redirects to the main wxHaskell repository.

Comment: Have you tried cloning it? I'm pretty sure that worked last time I tried (which wasn't so long ago, last november I think). You have to build the components of wxHaskell 1-by-1 though.

Comment: If by that you mean `git clone https://github.com/atzedijkstra/wxHaskell; wxHaskell/bin/mk-cabal`, then yes, I did, that's where the second set of error messages is from.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have cloned the github copy of wxHaskell:

```
git clone https://github.com/wxHaskell/wxHaskell
```

Then you tried to install wxHaskell without first installing any of its build dependencies.  Notice your error message:

```
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
wxcore >=0.90.1.0
```

That version of wxcore isn't on hackage (yet), but it is in the repo you JUST cloned (see https://github.com/wxHaskell/wxHaskell/blob/master/wxcore/wxcore.cabal).  So first go to the `wxcore` directory and cabal install that library.

EDIT: Notice the dependency tree goes deeper.  You'll need to install several `wx*` packages first.

Comment: So what specifically would I do about the `Graphics/UI/WXCore/WxcClassInfo` error?

Comment: To be specific: Unless I'm missing something, this seems less like a dependency error than the absence of a source file _in the wxcore package_ that is expected to be there. I don't know why it's not, and there are no forks on GitHub that have been updated more recently than the official repo.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but it took me a certain time to install wxHaskell (on Linux), therefore it is worth sharing. The instructions given at https://wiki.haskell.org/WxHaskell/Linux seriously need to be refreshed.

First:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libwxgtk-media3.0-dev
```

Then (after `cabal sandbox init` if you use sandboxes):

```
cabal install wxdirect
cabal install wxc
cabal install wxcore
cabal install wx
```